# Change of basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $T:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ is a linear map with $A=\left[\matrix{2 & -1 \\ 0 & 1}\right]$ being the matrix representing $T$ in the standard basis.

I wish to change the basis using $(1,2)$ and $(1,-1)$ as the new basis vectors.

I thought you would calculate the new matrix $A'$ by computing $C^{-1}AC$, where C is the transition matrix from the old basis to the new one. So $C=\left[\matrix{1 & 1 \\ 2 & -1}\right]$.

However, looking at my text book it says to compute just $C^{-1}A$ in this case. 
Does anyone know why this is?

They find $A'$ to be $\frac{1}{3}\left[\matrix{1 & 1 \\ 5 & -1}\right]$.

Comment: Your reasoning is right. If that's the result it could mean that you just want to change the basis of your codomain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generic vector has $v_e=v^1e_1+v^2e_2=\left(\begin{array}{c}
v^1\\v^2
\end{array}\right)_e
$ as old components
but if our base's change is
$$b_1=e_1+2e_2$$
$$b_2=e_1-e_2$$
and its matrix is
$B=
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1&1\\2&-1
\end{array}\right]
$, then the new components of $v$ are $B^{-1}v_e$.
So the formula
$$B^{-1}Tv_e=(B^{-1}TB)B^{-1}v_e$$ 
determines that $B^{-1}TB$ relates the new components of both $v$ and $Tv$.