# Vector as a tensor

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, tensors

If we define a $(p, q)$-tensor $T$ to the vector space $V$ as a multi-linear map:

$$ T : \underbrace{V^* \times \dots \times V^*}_{p} \times \underbrace{V \times \dots \times V}_{q} \to \mathbb{R} $$

And, a vector here being essentially a $(1, 0)$-tensor (I'm still not 100% satisfied with this), how would the components of the vector be defined in "tensor" form.

I.e.

Say $V$ is a 2-dimensional vector space with chosen basis $b_1 = (1, 2)$ and $b_2 = (1, 3)$.

Now, define a vector $v = (-2, -5)$ with respect to the standard basis ($(-1, -1)$ with respect to the chosen basis).

As a tensor, would $v_1 = -2$ or $v_1 = -1$?

Also, how would the tensor be defined?

I came across the following definition:

$v_i = v(\epsilon^i)$

$v(\phi) = v(\sum_{i=1}^3 \phi_i \epsilon^i) = \sum_{i=1}^3 \phi_i v(\epsilon^i)$

But while I can follow it, I can't make any sense of it. What does this actually mean? It would be helpful if I could see all the values and steps for a specific vector (like defined above). I think that if I can understand this, tensors over all will become much easier to understand.

Comment: The components of a vector with respect to a basis depend on the basis (which is why we say, "...with respect to a basis").

Comment: To expand on Travis comment: your question is I'll posed. Interpreting vectors as elements of a tensor space doesn't free you from having to specify the basis in this new space with respect to which you want to know components. You might want to think about a natural basis for the tensor space(or any other thay you are interested in) and then either figure out the components wrt this basis yourself or expand the question with the specification of this basis

Answer (score 0):

Let 
\begin{eqnarray*}
b_1&=&e_1+2e_2,\\
b_2&=&e_1+3e_2
\end{eqnarray*}
be your change of basis, which in matrix form is 
$[B]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1&1\\
2&3\end{array}\right]$ and 
whose inverse is
$[B]^{-1}=
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
3&-1\\
-2&1
\end{array}\right]$.
Now if you want to know which are the new components of, say,
$$v=-2e_1-5e_2,$$
you need to solve for $e_1$ and $e_2$ and substitute above to get
\begin{eqnarray*}
e_1&=&3e_1-2b_2,\\
e_2&=&-b_1+b_2,
\end{eqnarray*}
which in turn gives
$$v=-2(3b_1-2b_2)-5(-b_1+b_2)$$
$$\quad =-b_1-b_2.$$

One can see that the rule of how the components are related is
$$
\left[\begin{array}{c}
-1\\
-1
\end{array}\right]=
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
3&-1\\
-2&1
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{c}
-2\\
-5
\end{array}\right].
$$

Comment: Once you know how is the rule of components' change, you can deduce for any other tensor in the new basis.

Comment: But this is just the change of basis for a vector, which is simple enough. I was curious about the generalization for tensors. E.g. What does the tensor as a linear map mean? Does the linear map give back the components of the tensor? And if so, whether or not it is with respect to a particular basis.

Comment: Ok, once you understand that new components of a vector $v$, specified by $v_b$, and the old ones specified by $v_e$, are related by **$v_b=B^{-1}v_e$**, then you will understand how the components' of a tensor $T$ change... in a little while i'll elaborate. Meanwhile please check this another example http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1667915/change-of-basis/1667996#1667996

Comment: are you @kukac67 acquainted with the Einstein's sum convention like in, for a rank two-tensor, ${\mathbf T}=T_{ij}\beta^i\otimes\beta^j$?

Comment: not really, just that the sigmas are dropped.

Comment: in your last sentences' post, you are giving any covector $\phi=\phi_i\varepsilon^i\in V^*$ and with a vector $v$ you have $V^*\to\Bbb R$ which maps as $\phi\stackrel{v}\mapsto \phi_i v_i=\phi_1 v_1+\cdots+\phi_n v_n$ and it is linear.