# Change of basis of a linear application

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

Given a linear application $F: \mathbb{R} ^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} ^3$ and its expression under the form of matrix in standard basis, in order to change its basis to a $b$ basis, vectors of which are given, you would have to multiply the inverse of the change of basis matrix ${[I]}_{b}^{e}$  by the the given linear application in standard basis ${[F]}_{e}^{e}$ and the resulting matrix by the change of basis matrix:

$${[F]}_{b}^{b} = {[I]}_{b}^{e} \cdot {[F]}_{e}^{e} \cdot {[I]}_{e}^{b}$$

and has me very confused.

Isn't this equivalent to finding the coordinates of a vector in a given basis $b$ knowing its vectors and the coordinates of the initial vector in the standard basis?

As here: $\vec{v}_b = {[I]}_b^e \cdot \vec{v}_e$

Why shouldn't you stop after multiplying the linear application with respect to $e$ by the inverse of the change of basis matrix, but rather multiply that matrix by change of basis matrix?

Comment: maybe to your interest, you could understand better by watching and example in $\Bbb R^2$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1667915/change-of-basis/1667996#1667996

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure if that's really what you are asking, but you should pay attention to the fact that you may have different bases in the domain and codomain.

If you only apply the change of basis matrix on the right, you are changing the basis in the domain but not the basis in the codomain.

Comment: Ah! So, with linear applications, you need to change the basis of both the domain and the codomain? That would explain why you multiply the resulting matrix by the inverse of the inverse (the original change of basis matrix), since that would also change the basis of the domain. Which means that the notation with square brackets would be: ${[I]}_{domain basis}^{codomain basis}$?

Comment: You can use different basis on domain and codomain, but if you want to use the same, you have to multiplicate on the left for the cange of base matrix.

Comment: Isn't it inverse on the left, linear application in $e$ in the center and change of base matrix on the right? So shouldn't the change of base matrix be on the right?

Comment: Well, it depends if you are changing from b to e or from e to b. But to be clear, the formula you wrote in your post is the correct one.

Comment: If I'm changing from $e$ to $b$ where should it be? On the right as in the formula I suppose?

Comment: Yes, the formula is correct.